# how to pass domain name to the container in Container Instances, OCI?

Tags: django, docker, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am running Django application image in container that requires "CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS" to be passed as env variable, but it looks like container instances generate the domain after the deployment; or how can I set the env variable of container DJANGO_CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS="container instance domain" before running the container.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply run a  bash script that fetches the ip of your required container and update the env file . I faced the similar issue and this is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77397698/20175872).
Make sure to change the env variables in the `update_env.sh`  accordingly . In your docker-compose.yml file set `depends_on:` variable of django container to dependent container  (this will ensure your dependent container runs first and ip is known).